# java regular expression examples for match without length limitation

Tags: java, regex, expression, limit

i trying to write a regular expression for match a string starting with letter "G" and second index should be any number (0-9) and rest of the string can be contain any thing and can be any length,
i'm stuck in following code

```
String[] array = { "DA4545", "G121", "G8756942", "N45", "4578", "#45565" };

String regExp = "^[G]\\d[0-9]";

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    if(Pattern.matches(regExp, array[i])) 
    {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " - Successful");
    }
}
```

**output:**

G12 - Successful

why is not match the 3 index "G8756942"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
G - the letter G
[0-9] - a digit
.* - any sequence of characters
```

So the expression

```
G[0-9].*
```

will match a letter G followed by a digit followed by any sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `\d` it already means `[0-9]`

so when you say `\d[0-9]` that means two digits exactly

better use :

```
^G\\d*
```

which will match all words starting with G and having zero or more digits

Answer (score 0):

This regex would be fine.

```
"G\\d.*"
```

Because `matches` method tries to match the whole input,  you need to add `.*` at the last in your pattern and also you don't  need to include anchors.

```
String[] array = { "DA4545", "G121", "G8756942", "N45", "4578", "#45565" };

String regExp = "G\\d.*";

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    if(Pattern.matches(regExp, array[i])) 
    {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " - Successful");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
G121 - Successful
G8756942 - Successful
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"^[G]\\d[0-9]"
```

This regex matches "G" followed by `\\d`, then another number.

Use one of these:

- `"^G\\d"`
- `"^G[0-9]"`

Also note that you don't need a character class since it only contains one letter, so it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex `.*` will match any character after digit

```
^G\\d.*
```

http://regex101.com/r/uE4tX1/1

Answer (score 0):

> why is not match the 3 index "G8756942"

Because you match for a string starting with `G`, followed by a `\`, a `d` and exactly one digit. Solution:

```
^[G]\d
```